# not able to send html in mail function via ( php )

Tags: php, function, email

i have problem in `mail()` function

i can't send html in `mail()` function via ( php )

i use this statment:

```
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
```

Comment: please put your full code here

Answer (score 2):

You must specify `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` in your email headers for alternate message content types.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; "\n\n";
```

Comment: I think you mean for "alternate message content types" rather than "attachments"?

Comment: but now you've lost the HTML bit?

Comment: this result after change

Comment: Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in